# Deploy laravel 5 on Google Compute Engine

Tags: php, git, laravel, google-compute-engine, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5 and trying to deploy on GCE VM Instance.

I have an existing project and using git. I've pulled my code to /var/www/ , but when I tried to access to the path http://my-ip/my-project it showed a list of directories instead.

I've also tried install a new laravel 5 into /var/www, but still result the same. Although if I go to my-ip/laravel/public it show the laravel 5 welcome page. But if I go to my-ip/laravel/public/home it showed 404 not found (/home is the route provided by laravel 5)

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Are you deploying it with Apache ?

Comment: @NomanUrRehman Yes, I am

Comment: Are DirectoryIndex and DocumentRoot directives properly configured? Is there a proper htaccess file as stated at http://laravel.com/docs/5.0#pretty-urls in public home directory?